# HTML Navigation bar trouble snapping to top of browser screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the problem in action: http://crowleywebdesign.com

When I scroll down the navigation bar fixes at the top of the screen, but in the process, it causes the  underneath to snap upwards which I do not want.  I want the transition to be smooth.  This is the JQuery function I'm using:

```
<!-- JQuery function for navbar-fixed-top -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function () {
    //if you hard code, then use console
  //.log to determine when you want the 
  var d = $('#jumbo');
if ($(window).scrollTop() > d.prop("scrollHeight") ) {
  $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() < d.prop("scrollHeight")) {
  $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
}

});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the body needs a margin top pf 50px when navbar is fixed... Try this solution...

View it full screen and use the scrollbar slowly to see that its actually working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //if you hard code, then use console
    //.log to determine when you want the 
    var d = $('#jumbo');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > d.prop("scrollHeight")) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('body').css('margin-top','50px');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < d.prop("scrollHeight")) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('body').css('margin-top','0px');
    }

  });
});
if ($(window).width() > 739) {
  //Add your javascript for large screens here
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30
  });
} else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here 
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30
  });
}
```

```css
.boxes {
  background-color: linen;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://crowleywebdesign.com/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crowleywebdesign.com/resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://crowleywebdesign.com/resources/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://crowleywebdesign.com/resources/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="lock col-xs-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 text-center">
        <img src="img/logo/Lock.png" align="right" style=" width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <h1>Crowley Design &amp; Development</h1>
        <p class="lead">Web Design - Branding - Marketing - Search Engine Optimization</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Navbar-->
<div id="nav_bar" class="navbar-custom">
  <nav class="row navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--Brang and toggle grouped for mobile-->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;" href="#"><i>Crowley Design</i></a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="porfolio_title row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>Project Portfolio</h1>
        <!--<hr class="star-primary">-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="port_height row">
      <!--Start Swiper-->
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Queen's Space Conference -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal_QSC" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                    <h4>Space Conference</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/portfolio/qsc.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Circus tent" style="border-radius: 15px;">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- QUEngComp -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal_QUEngComp" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                    <h4>QUEngComp</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/portfolio/quengcomp.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Circus tent" style="border-radius: 15px;">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Light Bike -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">

                    <h4>Lit-Bike</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/portfolio/litbike.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Slice of cake" style="border-radius: 15px;">


              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Personal Website -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">


                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                    <h4>My Website!</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x"></i>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/portfolio/mysite.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cabin" style="border-radius: 15px;">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- QUExamBoss -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                    <h4>QU-ExamBoss</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/portfolio/quexamboss.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Circus tent" style="border-radius: 15px; border-color: black; border-width: 4px; border-style: solid;">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--End Swiper-->
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      </div>
      <!--End Swiper-->
    </div>
    <!--End Row-->
</section>

<section id="about">
  <div class="continaer">
    <div class="header_title row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <!--<hr class="star-primary">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="services_title row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>Our Services</h1>
        <!--<hr class="star-primary">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="continaer">
    <div class="contact_title row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <!--<hr class="star-primary">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked perfectly!  Another related question: I have ID's for my body content.  When I press links on the navbar, the page focuses at the ID, ex. the 'us' button jumps to the #about section.  The problem is, when the body jumps to the #about section, the navbar covers the 'About Us' title - I want the page to jump to the very top of the #about section without covering the title!

Comment: Use the `scrollTop()` function. Find the coordinate of the clicked link and offset it by 50 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, it would be nice if you try this.

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)

You can use Affix plugin which will solve your probelm.

OR

Add a css

```
.navbar-fixed-top + #portfolio {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

which will make your scroll smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I tried the affix solution as well, but it didn't work with the porfolio slider I'm using.  The affix navbar scrolled behind the portfolio items!  I'll look into affix more in the future :)